# "Save As..." in Mail Not Sorting by Date Received

Tags: macos, mail.app

I am a recent convert to Mountain Lion (new iMac arrived a week ago). Been using the "Save As..." option in Mail.app for years now to save chunks of email as RTFs.

Previously (in Snow Leopard), using "Save As..." would save your selected emails out into a single file (RTF by choice) in the sort order of your mailbox.

So for example, I sort by Date Received. My RTF file would be nicely organized by Date Received, and thus make a perfect monthly archive for thousands of emails.

Mountain Lion's Mail.app still has "Save As...". The only problem is that it appears to save the emails into my RTF file in completely random order. I cannot figure out WHAT the sort is, and it's completely derailed my workflow.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I can still copy/paste in the correct order, but that is only plain text and I need RTF for this.

Comment: Apple has either "improved" mail by implementing arbitrary new or changed features seemingly at random, or they had very poor quality control on the v6.2 release of Mail.app. (Or a combination of both "features" and bugs.) There are many other serious problems in Mail 6.2, i.e. it doesn't select the correct reply-to address from multiple accounts under certain (common) circumstances, etc. Just my two bits.